# Entity Framework: Select field name causing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The moment I mention field names when fetching data from db, I start getting errors.

Before my code was this and it was working:

```
var customer = from s in db.Customers
               select s;
```

The moment I change it to:

```
var customer = (from s in db.Customers
       select new
       {
        CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
        ContactName = s.ContactName,
        ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
        Address = s.Address,
       });
```

I start getting error as follows:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'PagedList.PagedList`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'PagedList.IPagedList`1[MVCCRUDPageList.Models.Customer]'.

My view looks like:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MVCCRUDPageList.Models.Customer>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

Comment: You need to project to a new `Customer` object, not an anonymous object.

Comment: now i add `select new Customer` for return but still getting error.

Comment: And is it the same error or different?

Comment: This error is because you are projecting onto a mapped class you need to be using the full namespace `MVCCRUDPageList.Models.Customer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because you are not sending the `Customer` model to the view.
By doing `select new { ... }` you are creating an anonymous object.

You may consider changing your code to:

```
select new MVCCRUDPageList.Models.Customer
{
    CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
    ContactName = s.ContactName,
    ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
    Address = s.Address,
}
```

You may still need to convert the `IQueryable` to `IPagedList`

Comment: i have given my full action code....tell me what to change in code and also in razor view if require. do i need to create a new customer dto class ?

Comment: you said "You may still need to convert the IQueryable to IPagedList" what i need to change in code?

Comment: You are already doing this in the "Full Code" you have shown.

Comment: job done...see my edit 2. thanks for your help and hint.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the view is expecting one type but you are passing it another type. The Linq `Select` method you have is projecting to an anonymous type instead of the expected `Customer` class. Change your code to match, something like this

```
var customer = (from s in db.Customers
   select new Customer //<--- This here, you may need to use 
                       //     the full namespace MVCCRUDPageList.Models
   {
    CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
    ContactName = s.ContactName,
    ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
    Address = s.Address,
   });
```

Comment: i have given my full action code....tell me what to change in code and also in razor view if require. do i need to create a new customer dto class ?

Comment: Your full code doesn't match what you have in your question, have you changed it? Does it work now?

Comment: You can't just keep changing your question. We have solved your problem and now you have another one. At least try to fix it yourself.

Comment: job done...see my edit 2. thanks for your help and hint.